# Elastic Weight Consolidation Algorithm Implementation in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I am working on an LSTM based model to predict logs-anomaly. My model architecture is as given:

```
______________________Layer (type) Output Shape Param # ================================================================= 
lstm (LSTM) (None, 5, 1555) 9684540 ______________________ 
lstm_1 (LSTM) (None, 1555) 19350420 ______________________ 
dense (Dense) (None, 1024) 1593344 ______________________ 
dense_1 (Dense) (None, 1024) 1049600 _______________________ 
dense_2 (Dense) (None, 1555) 1593875
================================================================= 
Total params: 33,271,779
```

I want to go for continual training avoiding catastrophic forgetting, I saw this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00796.pdf) on EWC. Yes, I am going to get totally different log files on incremental training, so catastrophic forgetting is happenning currently. I looked on internet and found only pytorch and tensorflow implementation of it. I am not very fluent at them, I am looking for some tensorflow-2/keras implementation of the same. I do understand the paper but not how to implement it. Is it possible to do in keras, if yes how? Any other simple continual learning approach is welcome!

Comment: Can you refer [Continual Learning with Elastic Weight Consolidation in TensorFlow 2](https://seanmoriarity.com/2020/10/18/continual-learning-with-ewc/) may help you. Thanks!

Comment: Looks good, my project was over 6 months ago although, but thanks, will check

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to apply the same algorithm (EWC) recently in the distributed optimization setting. I couldn't find a tensorflow-2 implementation. So I implemented it from scratch. You can find it here - https://github.com/stijani/elastic-weight-consolidation-tf2.git.
A demo notebook was included to demonstrate the code usage and sample result with the MNIST data set.